# HighCharts Angular - data from API not showing in chart

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, highcharts

I am trying to show the data from the [bgpie API](https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/00/mostfrequentstatefrequencycdf) in my chart.
The data property of the chart accepts this format:

```
chartOptions: Options = {
   
  ...

  series: [{
            ...
            data: [[1, 5], [2, 3], [3, 8]];
            ...
          }]
```

The format is an array of couples with the first value of the couple being the x-axis value and the second being the y-axis value. My API has a different format: `[{item1,item2}, {item1,item2}, {item1,item2}]`.

In order to change it to `[[item1,item2], [item1,item2], [item1,item2]]` I've done this:

```ts
chartDataX: number[] = [];
chartDataY: number[] = [];
chartData: any[] = [];


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartService.getMostFrequentUpdateData().subscribe(
      (data: ChartData[]) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          this.chartDataX.push(data[i].item1);
          this.chartDataY.push(data[i].item2);
          this.chartData.push([this.chartDataX[i], this.chartDataY[i]]);
        }
      });
    this.chartOptions.series = [
          {
            name: 'ao',
            type: 'line',
            data: this.chartData,
            color: '#009879',
          }
        ];

}
```

With `getMostFrequentUpdateData()` being a function that makes the http call to the API:

```ts
getMostFrequentUpdateData(): Observable<ChartData[]>{
    return this.http.get<ChartData[]>('https://bgpie.net/api/rrc/00/mostfrequentstatefrequencycdf');
  }
```

[This](https://github.com/mauri5566/sitocopy/blob/master/src/app/components/home/modal-most-frequent-update/modal-most-frequent-update.component.ts) is a public repository containing the project (There might be some merge conflicts).

Comment: @OlegValter Noted, thank you

Comment: Would be much easier to help you if you could resolve the merge conflicts in that code if it is yours or provide us with a working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `susbcribe` is async so your `this.chartData` is empty when you are assigning it to the chart object.

You can refactor as below with some suggestions to improve the code as well:

```ts
this.chartService.getMostFrequentUpdateData().subscribe(
      (data: ChartData[]) => {
        this.chartOptions.series = [
          {
            name: 'ao',
            type: 'line',
            data: data.map(e => [e.item1, e.item2]),
            color: '#009879',
          }
        ]; 
      });
```

Comment: Editor's note: please don't include chit-chat in answers, thank you. Re: comment editing - you can only edit them for 5 minutes + it is discouraged to give answers in comments (if you can provide an answer, of course). Other than that - all good!